# retrieve data from database recursively

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to node.js and working with database. how can I change my html to fetch next 4 items from database continuously?
I can show only 4 items now.

```js
const BlogPost = require('../models/BlogPost.js')


module.exports = async (req, res) =>{
    const blogposts = await BlogPost.find({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(4).skip(4).populate('userid')  
    
    res.render('index',{
        blogposts
    });
} 

d
```

```html
<div class="container homepage">
<div class="row row-cols-2  row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4  g-4">
  <% for (var i = 0; i < blogposts.length; i++) { %>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <a href="post/<%= blogposts[i]._id %>">
      <img src="<%= blogposts[i].image %>" class="card-img-top " alt="...">
    </a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"><%= blogposts[i].title %></p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted"><%= blogposts[i].datePosted.toDateString() %></small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% } %>
```

below code is for infinite scroll I wanna append my above html code every time user scrolls to bottom

```js
 window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
        divElement = document.querySelector("#divscroll");
      
        createObserver();
      }, false);
      
      function createObserver() {
        let observer;
      
        let options = {
          root: null,
          rootMargin: "0px",
          threshold: 1
        };
      
        observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
        observer.observe(divElement);
      }
      
      function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
       //add function for loading next items        
      }
```

Comment: Do you want to call the api every time someone scrolls to fetch the next 4 or do you want to make 1 api call, fetch all data and then display 4 at a time in the UI ?

Comment: I wana fetch all data and display four at a time.

Comment: I don't think IntersectionObserver is what you need to use here. You could listen to the scroll event on the div and update the UI